# Jquery Json ajax get receiving an exception immediately

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, rest

When I call a WCF service (which returns a string with json data in it) I created inside an html page using ajax and jquery, I receive no data. However if I hit the URL for the service directly within the browser it does return the data just fine.

When I use firebug within Firefox to track what's going on with the call, I immediately get this error:

ERROR: GetAllData :error, [Exception... ""  nsresult: "0x805e0006 ()"  location: "JS frame :: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js :: .send :: line 8068"  data: no]

My setup is as follows:

```
 $(function () {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'localhost:57211/GetAllData',
          type : "GET",           
          timeout: 10000,
          dataType: "json",
          success : function(result) {
             console.log( 'SUCCESS : GetAllData');               
          },
          error : function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
          var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
          console.log( 'ERROR: GetAllData:' + err); }   
         });
     });
```

Does anyone know what this error means? If not, how can I possibly debug it?
I've tried changing the version of jQquery to the latest and I still get the error, with obviously different line numbers.

Thanks

Comment: Probably same origin policy? Is this another domain, or the same domain as the page?

Comment: Make your URL absolute?  Also, are you serving up the page from localhost:57211?  You may be dealing with cross origin issues unless you support JSONP

Comment: hmmm.. I do see this when I run in Chrome, but not FF;   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.  So maybe it is that.

Comment: Ok.  So I moved it all.  But my response is too large.  I know how to set the MaxReceivedMessageSize in a client type C# consuming application.  Is there a way to set this inside a ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the error "Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP" which showed up in Chrome but not FF.

Answer (score 0):

If the url isn't relative it
 needs to have the protocol in it.

```
url: "http://localhost:57211/GetAllData"
```